# Errors appearing in CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators after upgrading to version 8.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui, community-toolkit-mvvm

After upgrading the Nuget package for CommunityToolkit.MVVM I have started getting errors appearing in the source generators - see screen capture below.

[image: screenshot]

Now I can't get rid of them, even downgrading back to version 8.0 doesn't seem to help.
I have undertaken a deep search and can not find any reason why these errors and warnings would be now there.

Has anyone seen this and how do I go about fixing this?

Using net 7 and language latest language version (11)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I can reproduce the problem when I added the **CommunityToolkit.MVVM version 8.2.0** into the maui project which target framework is **.net 7.0**.

But I can still build the project and use the api of the **CommunityToolkit.MVVM version 8.2.0** when I met the problem in your picture. It seems you don't need to worry about this.

In addition, when I added the **version 8.0.0** at first and then update it to **version 8.2.0**. The problem will not appear. And the result image:

[image]

Finally, you can open the package manager(or open the project's csproj file to delete the `<PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.0" />`) to uninstall the package at first and then added the **CommunityToolkit.MVVM version 8.0.0**. This will make the errors disappear.